# How to get contract wage from worked days in odoo8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

contract.wage is returning the wage of contract mentioned in payslip. But what if i have multiple worked days input and other inputs with different contracts of same person. We have a contract field for each input.

I want to get wage of each contract mentioned/selected in worked days inputs and other inputs.

Note: I want to access wage of contract in salary rules.

Any idea??

Answer (score 0):

You can can access the `wage` on Worked Days inputs from salary rules using the relation:

```
worked_days.WORK100.contract_id.wage
```

where `WORK100` is the code of the Worked Days input. In Odoo 10, this code can be named anything. For example, in my own case, I have input codes `NORMAL` and `SPECIAL` for normal and special work respectively.